# PHP mysql query 2 OR and 1 AND

Tags: php

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_country WHERE language='$lang' AND country_name LIKE '%".$_POST["query"]."%' OR country_second LIKE '%".$_POST["query"]."%'";
```

The above will not work. I want it to search in 2 fields (works) but based of the language I've set. But it simply skips the lang part

Comment: Are you sure `$lang` is set and have value? because you use  `$_POST` in other two

Comment: I see sql injection. Someone can delete your whole database by adding junk in `$_POST["query"]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$search = $_POST["query"];
if(empty($search))
{
    echo "Search filed is empty";
}
elseif (empty($lang)) {
    echo "Lang filed is empty";
}
else
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_country WHERE language='$lang' AND 
                        (country_name LIKE '%$search%' OR country_second LIKE '%$search%') ";
}
```

Wrap with `()`